# Configure default styles in LeafletJS

Tags: javascript, leaflet, vector

I want to change the default styles for vector layers in my Leaflet version 0.7.3. I can't find anything about that in in the documentation, so I made this hack:

```
map.on('layeradd', function(e){
  if(typeof e.layer.setStyle === 'function'){
    e.layer.setStyle(myApp.Map.Styles['default']);
  }
});
```

I don't find that a sustainable way of setting a default style, since I may sometimes want e.g. to overrule the default style or some other scenario.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite the defaults in L.Path with:

```
L.Path.include({options: newDefaultStyle});
```

e.g.:

```
L.Path.include({options: {
    color: '#dd8855',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
}});
```

Comment: It doesn't work for the options `L.Path.include({  options: {  color: '#ff0000' , fillColor: '#ff0000' }, log: function(){ console.log(this); }  });` - the log function works, but the options are overwritten by L's own default blue colour. Tried to look in source code, can't figure out why. Also tried using L.Path.mergeOptions(), same problem.

Comment: This works for me (kudos for noticing that L.include doesn't work with options) without any problems:

  `L.Path.mergeOptions({ color: 'red' });`

Just remember to overwrite the defaults **before** instantiating any vector objects.

Comment: Still doesn't work as expected. The inheritance from L.Path to other vector classes has taken place before I get the chance to run that statement, ie the change affects only L.Path, not eg L.Circle which remains blue. When I write `L.Circle.mergeOptions({ color: 'red' });` in my app, it works - for circles only. I'd have to do that for all L.Path subclasses. Doable, but not ideal. Sure, I could alter the source code, that would be a hack. I could make my own build, but hard to maintain and time consuming.

Comment: Bug reported here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3538

Answer (score 1):

It works to specify default style for all vector classes before you instantiate any:

```
var myStyle = {
    color: '#00767C'
  , fillColor: '#00767C'
  , opacity: 1
  , fillOpacity: 0.5
};
L.Path.mergeOptions(myStyle);
L.Polyline.mergeOptions(myStyle);
L.Polygon.mergeOptions(myStyle);
L.Rectangle.mergeOptions(myStyle);
L.Circle.mergeOptions(myStyle);
L.CircleMarker.mergeOptions(myStyle);
```

If you stick to only specifying for the super class L.Path, the child classes won't inherit the default style. L.MultiPolyline and L.MultiPolygon don't have a mergeOpsions method.